# Packaging directory with cpack for rpm

Tags: cmake, rpm, rpm-spec, cpack

I am trying to create a rpm package with directory with lot of files using cmake

http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list.html

> To make this situation a bit easier, if the %files list contains a path to a directory, RPM will automatically package every file in that directory, as well as every file in each subdirectory. Shell-style globbing can also be used in the %files list.

So with cmake I am using the following command:

```
INSTALL(DIRECTORY my_dir DESTINATION foo)
```

and I end up with a spec file with all the files (30k lines) instead of something like

```
%file
  my_dir
```

Did I miss something on my cmake/cpack command or the is no other way to do it?

(using a tar and an extracting it is not suitable)

Comment: Have you tried to play around a little bit with trailing slashes? They tend to be picky.

Comment: tried to add a '/' after my_dir and didn't helped :(